# Python: Quickest way of iterating through each DataFrame group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that can be segregated into multiple groups, perform function on, and then re-form the groups together as a single dataframe.

The problem is that the number of unique elements in each column is differenet, meaning to say, taking the example of the dataframe below, I would need a try, except statement as G would not exist for certain groupings for Eg a1,b2,c2,d1 does no exist.

What would be the quickest way of iterating through all these groups without needing a try, except statement?

```
A  B   C  D
a1 b1 c1 d1
a1 b2 c2 d1
a2 b3 c3 d1
a2 b4 c4 d1

As = df.A.unique()
Bs = df.B.unique()
Cs = df.C.unique()
Ds = df.D.unique()

 for a, b, c, d in itertools.product(As, Bs, Cs, Ds):
     G = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).get_group((a,b,c,d))
     Some more code below....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through groups like

```
for name, frame in df.groupby(...):
```

`name` should be the group, `frame` should be the output of `df.groupby(...).get_group(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your `a,b,c,d` tuples by what is actually available:

```
possible = set(itertools.product(As, Bs, Cs, Ds))
available = set(tuple(x) for x in df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].unique())

for a, b, c, d in (possible & available):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iter the `groupby` object:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"], "B":[1, 2, 1, 2, 2]})

for key, g in df.groupby(["A", "B"]):
    print(key)
    print(g)
```